# How to return rows when you have foreign keys to two different tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables - feed, posts, polls.

feed -

```
 id not null auto_increment,
 post_id int NULL,
 CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY post_id REFERENCES posts(id),
 poll_id int NULL,
 CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY poll_id REFERENCES polls(id)
```

posts -

```
id int not null auto_increment,
body varchar(200) not null
```

polls -

```
id int not null auto_increment,
question varchar(40) not null
```

Depending on whether the entry is a post or a poll one of the foreign key columns will be null. What I want to do is fetch both posts and polls from the feed table in descending order by the feed.id.

So far I tried the following query:

```
SELECT
    posts.body as post_body,
    posts.user_id as post_writer,
    polls.question as poll,
    polls.user_id as poll_writer
FROM feed
JOIN posts ON feed.post_id = posts.id
JOIN polls ON feed.poll_id = polls.id
ORDER BY feed.id DESC;
```

But it returns 0 rows. I would appreciate every help. Thank you I advance

Comment: You need  LEFT JOIN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    p.body
    p.user_id as writer,
FROM feed
JOIN (
    SELECT id, body, user_id, 'post' as Type
    FROM posts
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, question as body, user_id, 'poll'
    FROM polls
) p on p.id = coalesce(feed.post_id, feed.poll_id)
ORDER BY feed.id DESC;
```

And the need to JOIN to a UNION often indicates the schema should have been designed with one table from the beginning.

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice! It is of great value for a beginner like me. So if I understood that correctly it would've been better if I just added the polls in the posts table and created additional columns for them?

Comment: Yes. As for the additional columns, how the looks depends on the nature of the data: how much you have of each type. You might still have a separate `polls` table, for example, with a primary key back to the general `posts` table to keep the extra fields for that type of item. This saves space and memory, which can make things go faster. But you also might not, depending on how many of your posts are really polls, and how much data you have overall.